# Better filesystem for ZODB and Plone.app.blob

Tags: plone, zope

I am interested to know which Linux file system is best for hosting Zope's Object Database (Data.fs) and Plone.app.blob (blobstorage).  Various reviews from the Internet suggests that XFS is good for hosting both.  XFS is fast and works well with large files.  Anyone using XFS for Zope or Plone?  What optimization flags, if any, do you use for XFS?

Comment: You may want to explain further what kind of requirements the ZODB places on the filesystem (one large append-only file), as well as the blob storage (deep try of lots of files). Furthermore, this question *may* be better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: My use case is just for typical Plone installations.  Now that I know of severfault, I agree that this question is better asked there.

Comment: Some guidelines: If you have big files go with XFS. If you have a lot of files go with Ext4.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa your comment is more an awnser than a comment ;)

Comment: I have no clue how to tweak XFS. I assume Mark Shuttleworth has done it for me >_<

Comment: Thank you for the comments so far. FYI, I have [posted](http://serverfault.com/questions/400770/better-filesystem-for-zodb-and-plone-app-blob) this same question in ServerFault.

Comment: if you've performance in mind, use an SSD instead of a disk. Modern filesystems does generally a good job, ext4 is enough IMHO.

Comment: Note that the OP has reposted this at serverfault now: [Better filesystem for ZODB and Plone.app.blob](http://serverfault.com/q/400770) as well.

Comment: Closed as cross-site post: http://serverfault.com/questions/400770/better-filesystem-for-zodb-and-plone-app-blob